# Are many Dojo Toolkit users also using Python?

Tags: python, dojo

I've coming to be more interested in Dojo Toolkit which I find great, but are many Dojo users also using Python also? And why is it like that? 
I heard of Cherry Py (and why not Django?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Python team has been using Dojo on the client-side for a few years now, and we settled on CherryPy as our server-side about a year ago, and are pretty pleased with it. It's fairly minimal as web servers go, and enables us to customize the server behavior as needed. Initially we looked at Django and Turbogears as well, but we needed to do some things vis-a-vis user authentication, DB tuning, and templating that didn't really fit well in the "full stack" frameworks, so we've rolled our own stack instead.

As for why Dojo and Python go well together, I can only speak for myself, but they seem to have a similar "feel" to me, so I can move from writing code on the server-side and client-side without having to make too much of a cognitive shift.